# How to run discord bot on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, discord.js

I'm having some issues running my discord bot on my VPS
I can successfully run the bot on windows command prompt or in webstorm run function using node
'node fraithorbot.js'

But when I try doing this on my VPS system, I get this error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:807
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: /var/www/fraithorbot/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: invalid ELF header
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:807:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/fraithorbot/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
root@fraithor:/var/www/fraithorbot#
```

Does anyone know why this happens or how to fix?
I'm using ubuntu 20.04(I'm pretty sure)

Comment: Are you installing dependencies on the `ubuntu` or just copy and paste it there?

Comment: Did you installed the node modules on ubuntu, or uploaded the whole `node_modules` folder from your windows PC?

Comment: as far as I know you having trouble with install canvas.node check your VPS build tools and install logs

Comment: It would not work if you copy `node_modules` directly from your Windows machine to your ubuntu server. Omit `node_modules` when copying and run `npm install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, so I decided to share my solution

“It would not work if you copy node_modules directly from your Windows machine to your ubuntu server. Omit node_modules when copying and run npm install.”

Thanks to @user15517071